# What does "club strip" mean?

Tags: meaning

From http://www.fashionbeans.com/2013/mens-wardrobe-basics/

> The Oxford Cloth Button-Down Shirt (OCBD)
>
> If FashionBeans had a **club strip**, this would most definitely be it. A
>   firm favourite across the board, it is one of the first pieces I would
>   ever suggest to anyone.

What does "club strip" mean? I guess it is not "strip club"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** As the quoted text is from a London-based website, I believe JMB's answer is correct, that *strip* refers to a team uniform. But I'll leave my answer up, for if the author were from North America, I would have deemed it a typo. I've heard of *kit* before, but never this use of *strip* before; neither is in much use in the US or Canada, and it is not found in common dictionaries like MW or AHD.

--

My [initial] guess is that it is a typographical error, and the intended phrase is *[club stripe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/club%20stripe)*:

> **club stripe** *noun* - an arrangement of stripes of two or more colors on an article of dress (as a scarf or blazer) orig. representing the colors of a particular club and worn by a club member — compare [club tie](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/club%20tie)

The "club" these days is likely metaphorical; for example, a student or graduate of Princeton University might don an orange-and-black club stripe tie to signify their affiliation with Princeton, which isn't a private men's club however much it may feel like it at reunions:

[image]

The author, in order words, is calling the Oxford Cloth Button-Down Shirt a marker or symbol of FashionBeans staff, like a seal or a coat of arms, or perhaps like an unofficial uniform.

And yes, a *strip club*, an establishment where the staff remove their clothes for the titillation of the clientele, is something rather different.

Comment: -1. A "club strip" is the (football/soccer) club's uniform when playing matches against other football/soccer clubs in the UK.

Comment: This guess may be wrong, but it was still an interesting guess. I wasn't aware of either expression until I visited this question. I'm glad this answer is here, although choster may want to consider changing "My guess is" to "My initial guess was", and then adding some footnote acknowledging the more correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this alludes to a "group uniform". That is to say that we often use the word "strip" to talk of the "uniform" of a sports' team or club. Another word could also be "kit". Naturally, "club" in this case refers to the FashionBeans collective. Hence, they are saying that "should they have uniform/strip/kit, the Oxford Cloth Button-Down Shirt would be it".

Un/fortunately, "strip club" is not the meaning here! It's just an example of how compound nouns in English can so easily be confused!

Comment: This seems right to me.  I'll just add that the first dictionary I checked marked this usage as "British".  I don't think most of us Americans are familiar with this sense of *strip*, and this is probably why choster guessed incorrectly that it was a typo for "club stripe".  (I think your answer must be correct because of how it's used; "stripe" doesn't make any sense in context.)

Comment: As a native speaker of British English this struck me as the obvious answer.  Also nosing around fashionbeans.com I get the impression it's a UK-centric site, not least from the use of "colours" on the same page.

Comment: I think you're right, considering this is a London-based website. This meaning of *strip* for a *uniform* or *colors* is unknown this side of the pond, and found neither in AHD nor MW. But FWIW, *club strip* and *club stripe* here would mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: @choster A *stripe*, if the term would be used at all, would mean a specific element of the uniform's design. The word *strip* (in BrE) means the entire uniform, being shirt, shorts - or skirt - and socks.

Comment: @toandfro But metaphorically, they are the same thing— a uniform or other identifying clothing or accessory.

Comment: And probably quite British. I don't know it from Australian/New Zealand English.

Comment: @snailplane: Yep. It's definitely British Usage only. It's etymologically equivalent to the more common term from "football strip", where football (soccer) groups who wore a "strip" (B.Eng. originally Northern, from "cloth") or "kit" (B.Eng. from "1785" mil term, meaning "personal effects taken when travelling"). The colors worn by the club during matches was therefore their "club strip" (arch.) or "football strip".

Comment: To chime back in and agree with @NigelHarper and Matt: Fairly common to hear "strip" on the football (soccer) commentary of a Saturday afternoon. "Home strip"/"Away strip" etc. Definitely not a typo imo.

Comment: Just chiming in to say that I am a native British English speaker and I didn't understand this phrase until I read the answers.

Comment: @starsplusplus - I was the same at first glance, but I quickly realised when I followed the link in OP's question and saw the context.